# Why is TensorBoard Events showing weird squiggly plots?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

I've just learned how to view training summaries in TensorBoard after training. However, the plot shows up like this when it's fully loaded:

[image]

Is this a bug in Tensorboard? I'm using TensorFlow 0.11.0rc1 and TFLearn 0.2.2.

Comment: looks like it's showing events from multiple runs?

Answer (score 4):

Point anywhere on the graph and as you move your mouse you will realize that it shows the date and time of that particular event.

Do you see date and time aggregated because you ran the model several times?

You may also clear the graph and tally with verbose=2 in the model.fit method.

You can make use of the fact that it is possible to have sub-directories with in log directory you are launching tensorboard from... and they will be shown under different 'RUN'. This way you will also be able to compare models.

Hope this helps!